# How to detect abnormal values in python and create new variable

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my data named bp:

```
    a   b  c    d   e   ....
    1   2  5    3   999 ....
    2   4  2    4   2   ....
    999 2  8    7   999 ....
```

In this data I'd like to detect the columns which contain '999'. Once, we found it has '999', then we need to create a new variable named as the 'variable name' + '_check', for example, column 'a' contains '999', then we need to create a new column named 'a_check'. Then, in 'a_check', I would like to have value 1 if the original variable is extreme. So I expect to have this:

```
        a   b  c    d   e   a_check e_check
        1   2  5    3   999 0       1
        2   4  2    4   2   0       0
        999 2  8    7   999 1       1
```

I have a lot variables like these, so i am thinking about how to automate this process in python.

this is my work so far:

```
for columns in bp:
   if any(bp.columns == -999.000):
      bp['columns' + '_check'] = int((bp.columns == -999.000))
```

My code doesn't give error, but not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
pd.concat([df,(df==999).loc[:,(df==999).any()].astype(int).add_suffix('_check')],axis=1)
Out[624]: 
     a  b  c  d    e  a_check  e_check
0    1  2  5  3  999        0        1
1    2  4  2  4    2        0        0
2  999  2  8  7  999        1        1
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a check column where the condition is true,

```
df['check'] = df[df == 999].idxmax(1)
```

You get

```
    a   b   c   d   e   check
0   1   2   5   3   999 e
1   2   4   2   4   2   NaN
2   999 2   8   7   999 a
```

Now create columns corresponding to non-null values in check

```
for col in df.check[df.check.notnull()].values.tolist():
    df[col+'_check'] = (df[col] == 999).astype(int)
```

You get

```
    a   b   c   d   e   check   e_check a_check
0   1   2   5   3   999     e   1       0
1   2   4   2   4   2       NaN 0       0
2   999 2   8   7   999     a   1       1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this in python3:

```
for columns in bp:
  if 999 in bp[columns].values:
    bp[columns + '_check'] = list(map(lambda x: int(x == 999), bp[columns]))
```